# Rails query turns up empty, but same query retrieves records if serched in sql console

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I've run into an issue after creating a scope to return all users with a birthday between two days along with some other conditions. This information is supposed to be presented to the user dashboard.

If I refresh the page, there are 0 records found. If I run the scope in the Rails development environment console  it also returns 0 records. However, if I copy the query from the console when active logger is on, and put it straight into my SQL client, it returns the correct records. This scope is chained with a few other scopes as well, but if I were to remove this scope from the query chain, the query works, it just doesn't filter the date of birth ranges like I want this scope to do.

The SQL client is on the same database.

The scope:

```
where(
  "(date_of_birth <= ?) OR DATE_ADD(date_of_birth, INTERVAL ? YEAR) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
  min_age.years.ago.to_date, 
  min_age, 
  beginning_of_month, 
  end_of_month
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT `drivers`.* FROM `drivers` WHERE ( (date_of_birth <=
'1990-02-05') OR DATE_ADD(date_of_birth, INTERVAL 23 YEAR) BETWEEN
'2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30') AND (drivers.id NOT IN (SELECT
driver_id from follow_ups where team_id = 2)) AND
(average_miles_per_day >= 0.35) AND (travel_time < 2000) AND
(travel_time + (average_miles_per_day * 84) >= 2000)
```

Anytime Rails tries to execute this query it doesn't work. When executing this query in a SQL client, it works like a charm.

Comment: In your SQL query, you're showing a subquery as well, but not in the Rails code. Are you running one in your ruby stack? Also when you call the code in rails, you should be able to see the query in the logs. Maybe only when you run the rails app via server, but it might help.

Comment: Yes, there are other scopes chained with the above query as sub-queries. The logs and the console both show the query used to preform the search. In my description of the problem (above), I explained that I copied the query from the log (exactly how it was), and successfully executed the query in a sql client which returned the correct records.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry i missed that. Was wondering if maybe some conditional differences was happening due to additional parenthesis or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe... there is a problem with string to date conversion. Try to convert in your model using STR_TO_DATE() function. Please do it for each date... Let me know it it helps.

Comment: This is sort of what i suspected, i have yet to play around with different methods though. Ill try your suggestion now.

Comment: This wasn't the answer. But I just figured out what my issue was. Just like most suspected (even myself) it had nothing to do with the sql query. It had to do with a Class method that was called and how it manipulates the query.